# How should I administer the db on my site with Postgresql on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a new rails/postgresql web site  I am administering and want to do common database tasks that I would normally accomplish on PHPMyAdmin.  I've searched around but can't find any good admin tools.  Should I:

1. Write the db tasks I want to perform in ruby code and execute that?
2. SSH into the server directly and run things from the command line?
3. Is there a tool like PHPMyAdmin that I am missing? (Best option for me)

Comment: Maybe you can describe the tasks that you want to do. Some people (me) may not be familiar w/PHPMyAdmin. I would always opt for using code over the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gem [rals_db](https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/rails_db) may help. Of course it is not so powerful